# jslint: function out of scope

Tags: javascript, scope, jslint

I've been messing around with JS and various other web-related things lately and kind of learned the whole thing while applying it.

Out of interest I've put my code into a JS validator (jslint.com) and the result is staggering. I do understand most of the warnings, but there is one in particular that I can't get my head around. It reads `'doSomething' is out of scope`. Basically, this is the relevant portion, I believe. My entire script is structured like that: ready-function to kick things off and then it goes into the specific functions.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {doSomething();});
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log('did something');
}
```

I figured, a variable for instance is "out of scope" if it is declared in an if-expression and used outside of it. Like so:

```
function whatnot() {
    if (true) {
        var x = 10;
    }
    return x;
}
```

But how does that translate to my issue? Can you help me understand the problem and maybe give examples for a better code structure (or point me towards some articles that might help?)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it's out of scope of the `document.ready` block - that's likely what the warning means

Comment: Don't guess, make sure: if you run that snippet through JSLint on its own, does it still tell you it's out of scope?

Comment: if you directly copy and paste it in jslint.com it does still put out the warning, yes.

Comment: Maybe **$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {doSomething();});
});** is  being executed before doSomething is defined.

Comment: *"I figured, a variable for instance is "out of scope" if it is declared in an if-expression and used outside of it"* Not in JavaScript, not if you declare it with `var`. JavaScript didn't get block scope until last year, with the introduce of `let` (and `const` and `class`).

Comment: Everytime I see a question about JS Lint I find myself lamenting Douglas Crockford's failure to document (at least anywhere near the error messages) his highly opinionated thoughts on what makes good quality JavaScript. <sigh>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jslint is mistaken. That code will work without any scoping problems.

*However*, as a matter of style, you might want to define `doSomething()` *above* where it is used. Although `$('document').ready` doesn't get called until the entire DOM is rendered, and that shouldn't happen until after the script tag is fully parsed. As a matter of style, I prefer to define methods before I call them, and jslink would probably be satisfied if you moved your function definition inside of the `ready` block.

Comment: With the code presented, there is **no chance at all** that the `ready` call would occur before `doSomething` is defined. There's no "probably" about it. Function declarations are processed before any step-by-step code is executed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As jquery is implemented, sure. It's still good practice to define your function above where you use it.

Comment: @KenKinder: It has nothing to do with jQuery. It's how JavaScript, the language, is defined. Replace the `ready` call with a direct cal to `doSomething()`; still works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2se73shm/ Again: Function declarations are processed before any step-by-step code is executed. Re your "good practice" comment, that's purely a matter of style, and there are plenty of arguments on each side; irrelevant here.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea; thanks for the explanation. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your doSomething function **before** the $('document').ready line then jslint will stop complaining about the out of scope issue.

Comment: Upvoted Ken Kinder's answer as it explains better what is going on.

Answer (score -2):

In JavaScript, variables are [hoisted](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), essentially this means that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the script file, but remains undefined until it is declared.

If you move the function declaration above the function call in the click handler, the out of scope warning disappears.

Comment: *"In JavaScript, variables are hoisted, essentially this means that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the script file, but remains undefined until it is declared."* That's A) Irrelevant, the OP's question is about a function declaration, which behaves differently; and B) Incorrect unless you assume the variable is declared with `let`, not `var`. `a = 42; console.log(a); var a = 67;` is perfectly valid (if poorly-written) code in JavaScript which outputs 42.